# JButton usando JTattoo

Tags: java, java-swing, look-and-feel

Encontré que la librería **JTattoo** ayuda a cambiar la apriencia de la interfaz usando como ejemplo la siguiente línea

```java
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aluminium.AluminiumLookAndFeel");
```

El resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna forma de aplicar este comportamiento solo a los botones y no a toda la interfaz, es decir, puedo redondear solamente los botones con esta librería?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible siempre y cuando crees todos los botones secuencialmente

```
public void stuff(){
    JButton boton;
    LookAndFeel aparienciaOriginal= UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aluminium.AluminiumLookAndFeel"); // ponemos la nueva apariencia para los componentes nuevos

        boton= new JButton(); // aquí creamos los componentes nuevos para que salgan con la nueva apariencia

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(aparienciaOriginal); // regresamos a la apariencia original
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | InstantiationException | ClassNotFoundException e) {}

}
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873067/6999690

Comment: Gracias, funcionó bien